# How can i return a list of widgets using map function in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a list of widgets...

```
`List<Widget> commWidgets = [
Card(
  color: Colors.blueGrey[200],
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('Commodity 1'),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Opening Stock'),
          Text('Bought/Sold'),
          Text('Closing Stock')
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
),
Card(
  color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('Commodity 2'),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Opening Stock'),
          Text('Bought/Sold'),
          Text('Closing Stock')
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
),
Card(
  color: Colors.blueGrey[200],
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('Commodity 3'),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Opening Stock'),
          Text('Bought/Sold'),
          Text('Closing Stock')
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

];
`

and then i tried returning it using this line of code in my body property

```
Column(
    children: commWidgets.map((commWidget) => Widget(commWidget)).toList(),
  ),
```

but it fails with the error:
Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:70:51: Error: The class 'Widget' is abstract and can't be instantiated.
children: commWidgets.map((commWidget) => Widget(commWidget)).toList(),
^^^^^^

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `commWidgets` is already a list of widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a widget list like this by adding the same widget. instead, you can follow the steps below.

Create a model class for your data.

```
class DataClass {
  final String labelOne;
  final String labelTwo;
  final String labelThree;

  DataClass(
      {required this.labelOne, required this.labelTwo, required this.labelThree});
}
```

Create a list using above class

```
List<DataClass> dataList = [
  DataClass(
      labelOne: 'AAA',
      labelTwo: 'aaa',
      labelThree: '1111',
      ),
  DataClass(
      labelOne: 'BBB',
      labelTwo: 'bbb',
      labelThree: '222',
      ),
  DataClass(
      labelOne: 'CCC',
      labelTwo: 'ccc',
      labelThree: '333',
      ),
];
```

Then You can map those objects to a Column, a Row, or even ListView / GridView

**Sample Column**

```
Column(
   children: dataList.map((e) => Card(
   color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
   child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Row(
         children: <Widget>[
           Text(e.labelOne),
           Text(e.labelTwo),
           Text(e.labelThree)
         ],
       )
     ],
   ),
 )).toList(),
),
```

**Sample GridView**

```
GridView.count(
    childAspectRatio: 1.2,
    primary: false,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    children: dataList
        .map((e) => Card(
         color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
         child: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                     children: <Widget>[
                         Text(e.labelOne),
                         Text(e.labelTwo),
                         Text(e.labelThree)
                      ],
                   )
              ],
         ),
    ))
.toList()),
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a list of widgets, the map function isn't applicable here
EDIT - Fixed the problem
The Column widget will automatically render the widgets from the list

```
Column (
children: commWidgets
)
```

Comment: I tried this, I had the error "The element type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Comment: My bad can you check the edit, it should be children : commWidgets without square brackets

Comment: The commWidgets[ ]  needs an identifier in the square brackets. It's without the square brackets that gives the earlier error